Unhandled Exception: **GeminiException** => The connection errored:
I'm using flutter_gemini package in my project.
Yesterday it worked for me, I could chat with the Gemini AI, but today I can't. It is strange, because I did not touch the code. I receive this error:

[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled
Exception: GeminiException => The connection errored: Failed host
lookup: 'generativelanguage.googleapis.com' This indicates an error
which most likely cannot be solved by the library.

This is how the Gemini is initialized:
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
  ]);
  Gemini.init(apiKey: kGeminiApiKey);
  runApp(const MyApp());

And this is how I use it in my StatefulWidget:
 gemini.streamGenerateContent(question, images: images).listen((event) {
        // logic goes here
      });

Why wont this work for me?

are you sure its not a location issue?

try if you get a usable result from nslookup generativelanguage.googleapis.com

You have not provided details on your execution and network environment. Search the Internet for articles on debugging local network problems.

I got the same error message on my phone. It's working on Project IDX emulator though

This error is due to Flutter's release mode not putting the INTERNET permission in the Android manifest. So, you have to do that manually.
Add this permission to your android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml file
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

